# New typeorm project existing postgres database empty query results

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, typeorm

I have just installed and created a new typeorm project using the Readme on the typeorm git page. Trying to play with access to my existing postgres db used by a Java application. Having issues when trying to retrieve data using ActiveRecord. Any attempt to fetch data from the table appears to try to drop indexes and create the table. It already exists. Why does it want to create it? Is that a side-effect of using ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Found it. It's a function of the synchronize property in the ormconfig file.